Is there wtype-like tool that works with GNOME on Wayland?
According to the Ubuntu Manpages wtype is a xdotool type for Wayland. However when trying to run "wtype" I get the message "Compositor does not support the virtual keyboard protocol". Looking into this it appears that the Gnome compositor, Mutter, doesn't support the virtual-keyboard protocol, required for wtype to work on Ubuntu 24.04.
If anyone knows of an wtype tool that works with Gnome under Wayland please let me know.
NB. ydotools doesn't work either, it gives the error message
ydotool: notice: ydotoold backend unavailable (may have latency+delay issues)


ydotool needs you to run ydotoold as root first.

'I finally got 'ydotool' to work in Gnome on Wayland. I achieved this by installing 'ydotools' from source from https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool.git rather than from the Ubuntu repository.
Then I started by running 'ydotoold' as root but found that then I could only run 'ydotool' as root, which didn't suit my needs. I need to run 'ydotool' as a user.
So the issue for me was how to run 'ydotoold' on startup as a user. To achieve this I had to set up a systemd user service for 'ydotool'. After I did that 'ydotool' does exactly what I wanted 'wtype' to do
